# JQuery hide specific parent

Tags: jquery

I have this table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>*Two</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>One</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this JQuery

```
$("#show").click(function () {
$("td:contains('*Two')").show();
})
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("td:contains('*Two')").hide();
})

$("#hideRow").click(function (){
    $("tr:contains('*Two')").parent().hide();
})
```

I'm trying to only hide the row that has "*Two" but it hides all parent trs

Edit: I'm working on it in jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/tvsfbj8j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this lines:

```
 $("#hideRow").click(function (){
     $("tr:contains('*Two')").parent().hide();
 })
```

To:

```
 $("#hideRow").click(function (){
     $("td:contains('*Two')").parent().hide();
 })
```

Notice the change from `tr:contains` to `td:contains`.

Comment: wooow. such a simple mistake. thanks for finding it!

Comment: It happens with everyone! ;)